# SWIFT: Quick array with "direct" access

Tags: arrays, performance, swift, init

I want to use a huge array for counting. The number to count is the index itself. So it should look like

```
count[index]++
```

index is in 0..100000

But how should I declare it, if I have up to 100k entries? I don't want to insert 100.000 numbers with 0 before starting incrementing them. Any performant idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array` has an initializer for that:

```
var count = [Int](count:100_000, repeatedValue:0)
```

Comment: YES! That's exactyl what I needed! Thank you very much.